# Wine won't install although I've never installed it before. (12.10)

Tags: wine, package-management

For some reason, whenever I try to install Wine it says that the packages are corrupt:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Wine at **Software Center** by opening it (or *Dash >> Software Center*) and searching for *wine*.

Else, if it gives you some other error, try installing it on the terminal (*Dash >> Terminal*):

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

If it gives you some error, please paste it on a comment. You could also update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or, maybe if you installed Wine previously by error, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine && sudo apt-get purge wine
```

(Before installing)

I hope you solve your problem and tell us soon!

Comment: How do I put the error in a grey box?

Comment: Adding four spaces before the text will format the text as code :)